# Skipping specific number of lines after matching a word PERL

Tags: perl, lines

I want to match a specific line in a file, after matching the specific line i want to skip 5 lines and print the next one. E.g.

```
Lecture       <==(I want to match lecture)
1
2
3
4
5
Hello   <==(And then i want to print this line)
```

I tried doing this but it wont work:

```
if ($line =~ m/(Lecture)/) {
    $1 = $currentLine;
    if ($currentLine == $1+6) {
        print $currentLine;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a variable name other than `$1`, its value will be replaced by `Lecture` on each iteration (due to the (unnecessary) capture group in the regex). Also, the inner `if` should be outside the outer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the variable [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to keep track of the line number where the match occurred and skip the desired number of lines.  Saying:

```
perl -ne '/^Lecture/ && do {$l=$.} ; $.==$l+6 && print' inputfile
```

would print the 6th line after the match (in this case produce `Hello`).

Comment: `perl -ne '$l=$. if /^Lecture/; print if $. == $l+6' file`

Comment: if ($line =~ m/(Lecture)/) {  
  $1 = $currentLine;
  if ($currentLine == $1+6) {
   print $currentLine;
  }
  
 } 
i tried doing this but it wont work. Is there any problems that exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die "can't open data.txt: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ($line =~ /Lecture/) { #if a match is found ...   
        <$fh> foreach 1 .. 5; # throw away next five lines from iterator 
        my $next_line = <$fh>; # assign next one
        print $next_line;       # and print it
    }
}
```